# Extending maps from dense $*$-algebras of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-spaces

Given $\cal{A},\cal{B}$ two dense $*$-algebras of two $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ respectively, together with a $*$-algebra homomorphism $f:\cal{A} \to \cal{B}$, is it clear that $f$ extends to a bounded linear operator $f:A \to B$?

Comment: By "$*$-map" do you mean "$*$-homomorphism"?

Comment: yes, I have edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is a counter-example.

Let $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}\mc A$ be the algebra of complex polynomials restricted to $[0,1]$, with closure $A=C[0,1]$.  Let $X\in\mc A$ be the coordinate function, $X(t)=t$ for $t\in[0,1]$, so $X$ generates $\mc A$ as a $*$-algebra.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $x\in\mc B(H)$ be any non-zero self-adjoint operator.  Let $\mc B$ be the $*$-algebra generated by $x$ and let $B$ be the closure, a $C^*$-algebra.

Let $f:\mc A\rightarrow\mc B$ be the unique $*$-homomorphism with $f(X)=x$.  Suppose that $f$ extends by continuity to $A$, say $\pi:A\rightarrow B$ with $\pi$ bounded.  By continuity, $\pi$ is a $*$-homomorphism, and so is contractive.  But then $\|x\| = \|\pi(X)\| \leq \|X\|=1$.  As not every self-adjoint operator is a contraction, this provides the required contradiction.

Comment: That is lovely.

Comment: Can one exclude such examples by asking more of $f$?

Comment: Well, tautologically, yes!  ($f$ by assumption extends to $A$...)  Some years ago, I came across similar problems when working with Hopf $*$-algebras: it is rather subtle as to when you can extend such an $f$, and I don't recall having seen an "abstract" criteria: rather, there are domain specific arguments.  So without knowing a lot more about $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ and $f$ I doubt one can say more.  Of course, I could be wrong...

Comment: It would be enough to know that the unitization of $\mathcal{A}$ is inverse closed ...

Comment: Hi Matt, your comment rings a bell: was this one of your questions on here, or something we were discussing outside MO?

Comment: Well, it was 5 years and 2 careers ago...  I think this was just some private reading, and coming to the realisation that, well, this sort of question is subtle.  Probably to do with getting from CQG algebras back to the $C^*$-algebra formalism; maybe Dijkhuizen's and Koornwinder's paper.

Comment: Even though the answer is false in general, there are many special situations in which the extension does exist.  This is discussed in Section 4 of [R. Exel, T. Giordano and D. Gonçalves, Enveloping algebras of partial actions as groupoid C*-algebras, J. Operator Theory, 65 (2011), 197-210].